# Docker: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi

I'm trying to create a docker container for my fastAPI app. However whenever I try to run following compose file I get this error:

**Error**

```
docker logs api-api-1
```

```
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I first saw the error I thought that I run the database on the localhost of the container but I checked it and database is running on **0.0.0.0:5432**.

```
docker logs api-postgres-1
```

```
2022-11-22 05:08:23.971 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

**Compose.YAML**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: fastapilearning
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    environment:
      - ACCESSTOKENEXPIREMINUTE=${ACCESSTOKENEXPIREMINUTE}
      - ALGORITHM=${ALGORITHM}
      - DATABASEHOSTNAME=${DATABASEHOSTNAME}
      - DATABASENAME=${DATABASENAME}
      - DATABASEPASSWORD=${DATABASEPASSWORD}
      - DATABASEPORT=${DATABASEPORT}
      - DATABASEUSERNAME=${DATABASEUSERNAME}
      - SECRETKEY=${SECRETKEY}
    command: /bin/bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASEPASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASENAME}
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\booruledie\Documents\Git\freecodecamp\dockerPostgresData\:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

What's the issue here ?

I'm sure of the source code because when I try to run it on my local machine I didn't get any error.

Comment: what have you set for DATABASEHOSTNAME?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely PostgreSQL server didn't shut down correctly.

Try:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

You see:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 449) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

Then Kill the port:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Thanks for response, the problem was all about an environment variable. I forgot to change the DATABASEHOSTNAME's value to postgres from localhost.